# Query all UTXO's from a single Yoroi wallet via CLI?

Tags: cardano-cli, yoroi, utxo

I wanted to list all assets from my Yoroi wallet via Cardano CLI when I noticed separate privacy addresses had their own UTXO's. Is there a way to resolve all UTXO's from a single  wallet?

Answer (score 1):

The root key of a wallet is derived from BIP39 keywords. Then additional keys are derived beyond that. You would need to check each one individually for funds. You can use the [cardano-serialization-lib](https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib) for this. Many lite wallets like yoroi or ccwallet.io use this. More information about BIP39 can be found in my youtube video on the subject. https://youtu.be/5P1jx1ELUHk